# Node.JS and Asynchronous Messaging

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, typescript, soap

Ok, this is not what you think it is, I am not asking for help with the async/wait pattern or asynchronous programming I am well versed with those.  I am however querying whether something is possible within a Node.JS Express service.

**The Scenario**

I have a web service which is developed in Node.JS and uses Express.JS to expose some REST endpoints that a client can connect to and send a POST request.  For the most part these are Synchronous and will create a SOAP message and send that on to an external service and receive an immediate response which can then be returned to the client, all really simple stuff which is already implemented. So what's your point I hear you say, I am coming to that.

I have a couple of POST interactions that will build a SOAP message to send to an Asynchronous external endpoint where the response will be received asynchronously through an inbound endpoint.

**Option 1**: What I am looking for in these cases is to be able to build the SOAP message, create a listener (so I can listen for the response to my request), and then send the request to the external service which immediately returns a 200.

**Option 2**: When I setup the service I want to also setup and listen for incoming requests from the external service whilst also listening for REST requests from the internal service.

**The Question**

Is either option possible in Node and Express? and, if so how would one achieve this?

NOTE: I know its possible in C# using WCF or a Listener but I would like to avoid this and use Node.JS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) if it fits your needs.

> Option 1: What I am looking for in these cases is to be able to build the SOAP message, create a listener (so I can listen for the response to my request), and then send the request to the external service which immediately returns a 200.

Here's a very basic non-soap service implementation.

```js
let request = require('request-promise');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

//Validate the parameters for the request
function validateRequest(req) { ... }
//Transform the request to match the internal API endpoint
function transformRequest(req) { ... }

app.post('/external', function(req, res) {
  if(!validateRequest(req))
   return res.status(400).json({success: false, error: 'Bad request format');
  res.status(200).send();
  
  let callbackUrl = req.query.callback;
  let transformedRequest = transformRequest(req);
  let internalServiceUrl = 'https://internal.service.com/internal'
  request.post(internalServiceUrl, {body: transformedRequest}).then(function (internalResponse){
   //Return some of the internal response?
   return request.get(callbackUrl, {success: true, processed: true});
  }).catch(function (e) {
   request.get(callbackUrl, {success: false, error: e});
  });
});
```

> Option 2: When I setup the service I want to also setup and listen for incoming requests from the external service whilst also listening for REST requests from the internal service.

There is no "listening" in http. Check [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) if you need realtime listening. It uses websockets.

Your other option is to poll the internal service (say if you want to check for its availability).